# Is there a way to run a Method in a method that does not come from the class where this method is?

Tags: java, methods

Basicly what i am asking is this:

```
public void RunMe(Method method){

}
```

so basicly i mean if i can run the Method called "method" from that Method called `RunMe(Method....`

Comment: Do you mean `method.invoke(instance);` ?

Comment: Does that run the code in the method that i put?

Comment: There is a way to run a method within a method, but not the way you are attempting. First of all, in the method block you can create an instance of the class that has Method B and then use that instance to call Method B.

Comment: Do you mean passing some kind of callback delegate to the method?

Comment: Could you make the method a static method in Method.class Then call it inside the public void RunMe() { Method.method(); }

Answer (score 3):

Use a Method as an argument isn't the right way.

Hum the best way (I think) to do something like that is to use the `reflection`.

Example:

```
public void RunMe(Object target, String methodName){
    Class c = target.getClass();
    Method m = c.getMethod(methodName, new Class[0]);
    m.invoke(target, new Object[0]);
}
```

If you need more details about it you can [check here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a method outside its class, the method cannot be a `private` method. If you don't know what `private`, `public`, `static`, etc. is, read about access-level modifiers.

Let's say that you have a class called `MyClass` with a method called `myMethod`, and your `main()` in a class called `MainClass` then you would do it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();
    }

    void foo() {
        MyClass.myMethod();
    }
}
```

`myMethod` has to be static if you want to reach the method without creating an object of `MyClass`. However, you might dislike static and have no problem with creating an object. In that case, do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo();
    }
    void foo() {
        MyClass a = new MyClass();
        a.myMethod();
    }
}
```